# Remove animation of specific item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I know that I can set the following on my RecyclerView, but this removes ALL animations for ALL items:

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

Is there a way that I can remove the `notifyItemChanged()` animation on a **specific item** in my adapter?

Comment: use notifyDatasetChanged() in place of  notifyItemRemoved() or notifyItemRangeChanged(). this will remove the item remove animation

Comment: That updates the whole dataset. I only want to update the one item.

Comment: you can fremove that item like list.remove(itemPosition) then notify the adapter. this will remove the item and recycler/list view will be updated

Comment: Again, notifyDatasetChanged() tells the RecyclerView to update all items in view, not just the one that I want to change.

Comment: And what you want to do exactly ....... remove the item ...... if you dont update the dataset how the recyclerview will be udated fromm older view to new view because after removing the item your list will be updated not the recyclerview... to update the view you have to notify the data

Comment: Literally all I want to do is remove the animation of `notifyItemChanged()` for only the *first item in the list*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146368/discussion-between-sahil-kumar-and-user841869).